# MariaDB: Create dynamic PrepareStatement inside a Procedure

Tags: mariadb, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, prepared-statement

I am trying to make a stored procedure which returns me the records of a table that match filters that can be applied in layers.

The procedure receives certain variables as parameters and I want to construct a [PrepareStatement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/prepare-statement/) that adds the non-null variables as filters. I am using **MariaDB 10.6.2**

The table I am working on (removing the foreign keys) looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Thesis_Detail(
    thesis_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    year SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    file VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    abstract TEXT NOT NULL,
    uploaded_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    INDEX(year),
    FULLTEXT(title)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

The goal itself is to create it this way

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UThesis.searchThesisByFilters(
    IN year_in SMALLINT,
    IN title_in VARCHAR(255),
    IN limit_in TINYINT,
    IN offset_in TINYINT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE first BIT DEFAULT 0;

    SET @sql = 'SELECT TD.title AS title,' ||
               'TD.year AS year,' ||
               'TD.file AS path,' ||
               'TD.abstract AS abstract,' ||
               'TD.thesis_id AS thesis_id ' ||
               'FROM Thesis_Detail TD ';

    IF NOT ISNULL(title_in) THEN
        SET first = 1;
        SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)';
    END IF;

    IF NOT ISNULL(year_in) THEN
        IF first THEN
            SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE';
        ELSE
            SET @sql = @sql + ' AND';
        END IF;
        SET @sql = @sql + ' TD.year = ?';
    END IF;

    SET @sql = @sql + ' LIMIT ?  OFFSET  ?';

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt using title_in, year_in, limit_in, offset_in;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is that the following line would be dynamic, that is, it may or may not have the `title_in` or  `year_in`

```
EXECUTE stmt using title_in, year_in, limit_in, offset_in;
EXECUTE stmt using year_in, limit_in, offset_in;
EXECUTE stmt using title_in, limit_in, offset_in;
EXECUTE stmt using limit_in, offset_in;
```

This example can be solved with combinations of whether one or two are null, but the problem is that I have to apply more filters. In total there are **5 filters** but doing the case of each combination ends up being terrible. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

In the first link they make use of CONCAT, but I don't know if that makes the procedure vulnerable to SQL injections.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UThesis.searchThesisByFilters(
    IN year_in SMALLINT,
    IN title_in VARCHAR(255),
    IN limit_in TINYINT,
    IN offset_in TINYINT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE first BIT DEFAULT 0;

    SET @sql = 'SELECT TD.title AS title,' ||
               'TD.year AS year,' ||
               'TD.file AS path,' ||
               'TD.abstract AS abstract,' ||
               'TD.thesis_id AS thesis_id ' ||
               'FROM Thesis_Detail TD ';

    IF NOT ISNULL(title_in) THEN
        SET first = 1;
        SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)';
    END IF;

    IF NOT ISNULL(title_in) THEN
        IF first THEN
            SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE';
        ELSE
            SET @sql = @sql + ' AND';
        END IF;
        SET @sql = @sql + CONCAT(' TD.year = ', year_in);
    END IF;

    SET @sql = @sql + CONCAT(' LIMIT', limit_in, ' OFFSET ', offset_in);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only security risk is title_in, as all other are checkd and give an error if they are not a Number.

So you can't contaminate the title_in, instead you make it a prepared statennet.

Basicallye you can make title_in and year_in  prepared, if you wish, but as i said ints aren't security issue

So your code would look like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UThesis.searchThesisByFilters(
    IN year_in SMALLINT,
    IN title_in VARCHAR(255),
    IN limit_in TINYINT,
    IN offset_in TINYINT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE first BIT DEFAULT 0;

    SET @sql = 'SELECT TD.title AS title,' ||
               'TD.year AS year,' ||
               'TD.file AS path,' ||
               'TD.abstract AS abstract,' ||
               'TD.thesis_id AS thesis_id ' ||
               'FROM Thesis_Detail TD ';

    IF NOT ISNULL(title_in) THEN
        SET @title := title_in;
        SET first = 1;
        SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)';
    END IF;

    IF NOT ISNULL(title_in) THEN
        IF first THEN
            SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE';
        ELSE
            SET @sql = @sql + ' AND';
        END IF;
        SET @sql = @sql + CONCAT(' TD.year = ', year_in);
    END IF;

    SET @sql = @sql + CONCAT(' LIMIT', limit_in, ' OFFSET ', offset_in);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    IF NOT ISNULL(title_in) THEN
    EXECUTE stmt USING @title;
    ELSE
       EXECUTE stmt;
    END IF;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //
```

Comment: But if there is another text filter then there is no other option? For now it solves my problem but I'm guessing if there is some way to solve for example 3 text filters

Comment: you string would be  `'+max +nbk +text -mine'` or '1932,Ford,TBird'

Comment: No, I mean like title, author, keywords filter. I didn't answer before because I didn't understand your comment haha

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour

I have a question here.
In the procedure I would like to do something more ...

I would like to:

1. have some columns passed as parameter of the procedure
2. more complex to have a loop on all the records found by the query and for example for each record found do a insert into e debugging table

So the issue here is that the loop may not know the columns ad they might be dynamic
so how can I do something

Which will replace a static code like this

```
for rec in(select Id, title from MY_TABLE where .....) 
    loop
        nbRec := nbRec+1;
        CALL  my_debug ('MY_TABLE ', rec.Id || ' ¤ ' || rec.title)
        ;
    end loop
    ;
```

To something much more dynamic

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT ...  '; -- the select beign build usign the parameters passed to the proc
for rec in(select Id, title from MY_TABLE where .....) 
    loop
        nbRec := nbRec+1;
        CALL  my_debug ('MY_TABLE ', rec.Id || ' ¤ ' || rec.title)
        ;
    end loop
    ;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
for rec in(??????) 
    loop
        nbRec := nbRec+1;
        CALL  my_debug ('MY_TABLE ', ???????)
        ;
    end loop
    ;
```

my doubt is on the ??????
you saw my expect format was to have a ' ¤ ' between each column results